# all links redirects to localhost/dashboard/ with codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am very much new to codeigniter. 
I have a codeigniter project and i need to do some changes.I have pasted it into htdocs and changed application/config/config.php 's base_url to localhost's path.

and changed database connection inside application/config/database.php

after above changes , my index page is opening well on localhost.But all the links from index page redirects to http://localhost/dashboard/  .

I did not changed .htaccess  file content.
here it is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: Its with this `RewriteBase /`

Comment: you need to remove `index.php` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you need to remove `index.php` then use this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: using this code , now it is not redirecting to localhost/dashboard. It is opening links now like , http://localhost/backup-3.1.2017_17-43-40_travocoaster/homedir/public_html/brochures  , but page says An Error Was Encountered , Unable to load the requested file: frontend/brochures.php . for all the url s

Comment: how you call this file `frontend/brochures.php` add code please

Comment: for example this link http://localhost/backup-3.1.2017_17-43-40_travocoaster/homedir/public_html/brochures says , Unable to load the requested file: frontend/brochures.php . But I did not find any route related to this , inside application/config/routes.php file .

Comment: no i asked how you call this file on your view `frontend/brochures.php` ??

Comment: I just found that inside views/ folder there is no file "brochures.php" hence error.  thanks for your time .

Comment: @NiraliJoshi no isses enjoy coding

Comment: Thank You @Abdulla Nilam , thanks for this above answer -  .htaccess file settings , this solved my redirection issue...

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine on
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and solved by doing the following.

If you are using CodeIgniter 4, go to `app/config/app.php` file and replace this:

```
public $indexPage = 'index.php';
```

With this:

```
public $indexPage = '';
```